# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy on front-page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have registered a custom post type "Projects" and also registered a custom taxonomy for that Post Type called "Project Categories".  On my home page I have a div in which I would like to list all projects and terms fro the "Project Categories" taxonomy. Currently, I am only able to get the lists of the terms.  Can someone tell me why I am unable to get the terms to display. Currently, I have:

```
<div class="list-container">
    <?php 
    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'projects' ) );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php $taxonomy = 'project_categories';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
                            ?>
    <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $cat): ?>
        <li><?php $cat; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!--end list-container-->
```

Another question I have is, is it better to include the taxonomies inside or outside of the query_posts loop?

Comment: <li><?php $cat; ?></li> you have missed echo here

Answer (score 1):

`get_terms($taxonomy)` returns a array of objects (see [get_terms() in WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term)), so in order to print the name you should use `<?php echo $cat->name ?>` (and don't forget the echo).

I tried to correct your code. See comments within the code block for details:

```
<?php 
    // keep your queries outside the loop for more readable code
    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'projects' ) );
    $taxonomy = 'project_categories';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>

<!-- <li> should be enclosed in <ul> or <ol> -->
<ul class="list-container">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $cat): ?>
        <li><?php echo $cat->name; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul><!--end list-container-->

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**Sidenote:** Either you use `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` or you use `<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`. The former will do all the magic automatically, and is recommended in this case.